# gdb: How to discard line overflow (instead of wrapping)?

Tags: c, gdb

In gdb, I can adjust the line width with `set width <n>` and gdb will then try to find a good place to wrap the line such that its length doesn't exceed `n` characters.

But how do I *discard* the remaining line?

Answer (score 2):

> But how do I discard the remaining line

I don't believe GDB has such an option (and it's most unusual to only care about part of the output).

One thing you *could* do is run GDB in an `emacs` buffer, and set it to truncate lines.

Comment: "It's most unusual to only care about part of the output."  I don't know about that.  I have some boost::multi_index symbol names that take up 5 lines at a buffer width of 240.  It's a lot of clutter, and I truly do not care about "all" of the output for those lines.  I'm almost always debugging *my* code.